# AngularJS: Filter and sort ng-repeat on data from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, filter, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

SThis is an Angularjs ng-repeat loop where rssSources is a JSON array. Each element represents an object with parameters of an RSS feed such as titel, url and tags.

```
<li ng-repeat="ssrc in rssSources | filter:qsources | filter:qsources2 | filter:isCategory | limitTo:140 | orderBy: 'atitle'"><a ng-click="selectModel(ssrc.aurl)" target="_blank">{{ssrc.atitle}}</a></li>
```

I can filter it like so

```
<input type="text" ng-model="qsources" placeholder="Select Feed">
```

The problem: as long as rssSources is defined in the template - $scope.rssSources = [{}{}{}] - filtering with the input works and the other filters in ng-repeat work as well.

But as soon as I get rssSources from Firebase, the data are still shown but neither filter works. Plus, the sort does not work.

I have found a workaround at least for binding  ng-repeat to the input field - it is really ugly but it works:

```
ng-repeat="ssrc in rssSources" ng-show='ssrc.atags.indexOf(qsources) > -1 || qsources == undefined'
```

Looking for the clean AngularJS-ish solution. Some basic thing is missing here to make a data source from Firebase filterable and sortable.

Comment: That's a lot of filters. Each of those involves iterating all the data and creating a new array. You'll probably want to combine those into a custom query and do that work yourself for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, this is what I felt would be right. I am very new to AngularJ and to the MVC thinking in general. Therefore I tend to include too much logic into the view. Working on it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [orderByPriority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#orderbypriority) in order to apply filters on your data, which I guess it's comming from Firebase.

Try this instead:

```
<li ng-repeat="ssrc in rssSources | orderByPriority | filter:qsources | filter:qsources2 | filter:isCategory | limitTo:140 | orderBy: 'atitle'">
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, Jobsamuel. I had already tried it but it throws an error which I still have sort out. Console.log: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=orderByPriorityFilterProvider%20%3C-"<!-- ngRepeat: ssrc in rssSources | orderByPriority | filter:qsources | filter:qsources2 | filter:isCategory | limitTo:140 | orderBy: 'atitle' -->"rderByPriorityFilter

Comment: Did you include `$firebase` as a dependency in your angular module? It seems to be missing that.

Comment: Thank you @Jobsamuel. Presently my module is ************ angular.module('feedReaderApp', [])
.controller('RssFeedCtrl', [
 '$http', '$interval', '$scope', '$sce', '$timeout', function($http, $interval, $scope, $sce, $firebase, $angularFire, $timeout) { .... ************* When in include firebase like so *********** angular.module('feedReaderApp', []) ********* then console.log says "uncaught object" and it points to angular.js at function minErr(module).

Comment: Sorry. Should be: When in include firebase like so *********** angular.module('feedReaderApp', ['$firebase']) *********